# Not getting output while parsing the xml

Tags: android, xml-parsing, response

I am using soap webservice and I have got the proper response, now i want to parse the response I have written code for that but I am not getting output, Can someone help me ?

My main class is

```
public class Mylearning extends ListActivity {
    //ArrayList<cat> list = null;
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION="http://yyy.mobi/GetLearningPortalsList";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME ="GetLearningPortalsList";
    private static final String NAMESPACE ="http://yyy.mobi/";
    private static final String URL = "http://webservices.yyy.mobi/MobileLMSServices.asmx";
    private Bundle bundleResult = new Bundle();
    private JSONObject JSONObj;
    private JSONArray JSONArr;
    //private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myList;
    SoapObject request;
    TextView tv;
    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;               
    ListView mainListView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylearning);

        //mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_listview);
        request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("SiteURL","http://www.yyy.mobi/");
        request.addProperty("PageID","1");
        request.addProperty("SearchText","");

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();   

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        SoapObject result = null;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        AndroidHttpTransport sab = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        sab.debug = true;
        try {
            sab.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            if (envelope.getResponse() != null) {
                result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                String[] values = new String[result.getPropertyCount()];
                int j = result.getPropertyCount();
                String repons=result.toString();
            //  Log.d("result",repons.toString());
                Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(repons);
                int numResults = XMLfunctions.numResults(doc);

                if((numResults <= 0)){
                    Toast.makeText(Mylearning.this, "Geen resultaten gevonden", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                    finish();
                }

                 NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("result");
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {                           
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
                    map.put("Course", XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "Course"));
                    map.put("Description", "Description:" + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "Description"));
                    map.put("icon", "icon: " + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "icon"));
                    mylist.add(map);            
                }

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.rowmylearning, 
                        new String[] { "Course", "Description","icon" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.txt1, R.id.txt2,R.id.img1 });

                setListAdapter(adapter);
                final ListView lv = getListView();

                lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                        HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                        Toast.makeText(Mylearning.this, "Course '" + o.get("Course") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                    }
                });

            }
        }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
}
```

My XMLFunction class is

```
public class XMLfunctions {

    public final static Document XMLfromString(String repons){

        Document doc = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(repons));
            Log.d("message",repons.toString());
            doc = db.parse(is);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;

    }

    /** Returns element value
      * @param elem element (it is XML tag)
      * @return Element value otherwise empty String
      */
     public final static String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node kid;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( kid = elem.getFirstChild(); kid != null; kid = kid.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( kid.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return kid.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }
    public static int numResults(Document doc){     
        Node results = doc.getDocumentElement();
        int res = -1;

        try{
            res = Integer.valueOf(results.getAttributes().getNamedItem("count").getNodeValue());
        }catch(Exception e ){
            res = -1;
        }

        return res;
    }

public static String getValue(Element item, String str) {       
    NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
    return XMLfunctions.getElementValue(n.item(0));
}
```

}

My response is as follows

```
 04-25 11:53:32.806: D/status(2924): GetLearningPortalsListResponse{GetLearningPortalsListResult=anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; }; }; }; element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; 
diffgram=anyType
{
NewDataSet=anyType

{
Table=anyType
{
ROWID=1; SiteID=7; PortalName=Pinneast; mSiteURL=http://pinneast.xxx.mobi/; ProtalLogo=/Content/SiteConfiguration/7/MyportalLogo.gif; Description=Pinneast is focused on improving business performance through human capital development and experienced in helping organizations of all sizes and across all industries; 
};

Table=anyType   
{
ROWID=2; SiteID=10; PortalName=Coach Institute; mSiteURL=http://coachinstitute.xxx.mobi/; ProtalLogo=/Content/SiteConfiguration/10/MyportalLogo.gif; Description=The Coaching Institute, where you are learning from someone who “does” and not just someone who “teaches”. We can train you to be a successful coach.; 
}; 

Table=anyType
{
ROWID=3; SiteID=12; PortalName=Ready Courses; mSiteURL=http://readycourses.xxx.mobi/; ProtalLogo=/Content/SiteConfiguration/12/MyportalLogo.gif; Description=When you work with us, you get a professional team of e-learning and corporate training professionals who are passionate about getting the best technology implemented without high costs.; 
}; 

Table=anyType
{
ROWID=4; SiteID=13; PortalName=A Step to Gold; mSiteURL=http://asteptogold.xxx.mobi/; ProtalLogo=/Content/SiteConfiguration/13/MyportalLogo.gif; 
Description=The Ballroom is solely owned and operated by Melanie Dale. It has a 2400 square foot floating floor, and two other teaching studios.; 
}; 


Table=anyType
{ROWID=5; SiteID=14; PortalName=In Sync Training; mSiteURL=http://insynctraining.xxx.mobi/; ProtalLogo=/Content/SiteConfiguration/14/MyportalLogo.gif; 
Description=InSync Training offers a variety of consulting, development and delivery services to support synchronous training initiatives.; 
}; 

Table=anyType
{ROWID=6; SiteID=15; PortalName=Total Motion Release; mSiteURL=http://totalmotionrelease.xxx.mobi/; ProtalLogo=/Content/SiteConfiguration/15/MyportalLogo.gif;
 Description=Two stories emphasize how Tom Dalonzo-Baker discovered Total Motion Release.; }; 

Table=anyType
{ROWID=7; SiteID=16; PortalName=Polaris Consultants; mSiteURL=http://polaris.xxx.mobi/; ProtalLogo=/Content/SiteConfiguration/16/MyportalLogo.gif; 
Description=Founded in 1997, and located adjacent to the Research Triangle Park in North Carolina, Polaris Clinical Research Consultants, Inc.; };

Table=anyType
{ROWID=8; SiteID=17; 
PortalName=Develop Mentor Training; mSiteURL=http://developmentor.xxx.mobi/; ProtalLogo=/Content/SiteConfiguration/17/MyportalLogo.gif; Description=DevelopMentor provides in-depth, hands-on training for experienced developers.; }; 


Table=anyType
{ROWID=9; SiteID=18; PortalName=Cranky Middle Manager; mSiteURL=http://cmm.xxx.mobi/; ProtalLogo=/Content/SiteConfiguration/18/MyportalLogo.gif; 
Description=If you've ever felt like you're trapped between the idiots who make the decisions and the morons who won't do as their told.; };

Table=anyType
{ROWID=10; SiteID=19; 
PortalName=ITPreneurs; mSiteURL=http://itpreneurs.xxx.mobi/; ProtalLogo=/Content/SiteConfiguration/19/MyportalLogo.gif; 
Description=ITpreneurs is the leading training solutions company in the IT management and IT governance best practices domain.;
 }; 
Table1=anyType{TotalRecordsCount=387; }; 
}; 
}; 
}; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have count tag in your xml.have you checked?

because in numResults function.it returns result according to count tag in xml.

Comment: No i dont have any count tag in my xml,I have changed it to table tag which is in my xml but still its not working

Comment: I have added My response please check it above

Comment: response is not in XML format .It must be in XML format.    <results count="6">
  <result>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Mark</name>
   <score>6958</score>
 </result>                                                  </results>

Comment: follow this link http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parseread-xml-data-into-android-listview/

Comment: I have followed the same link but problem is in there response they have parent tag count having id as 6. But in my response no such id is there for the parent tag

Comment: you can parse only xml with this code.and your response is not in xml format .so it will not work.try some other things to parse your response.

Comment: i dont know how to parse this response.but you can change ur web service response into xml or json.so you can easily parse it.

Comment: how to convert this response to xml ??

Answer (score 0):

This code parses XML data from web service. It Works.

```
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_servis_uygulamasi);

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);   

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {    
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
            String pSoapAction  = "http://tempuri.org/GetMagazaList";
            String pMethodName  = "GetMagazaList";
            String pNameSpace   = "http://tempuri.org/";
            String pUrl         ="";

            SoapObject result =(SoapObject)getWebServisDATA(pUrl, pMethodName, pNameSpace, pSoapAction, "333");

            TextView   tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            try
            {                                                                              
                               SoapObject soapObjectGetProperty=(SoapObject)result.getProperty(0);

                               SoapObject resDiff  = (SoapObject)soapObjectGetProperty.getProperty("diffgram");
                              SoapObject resDocEl = (SoapObject)resDiff.getProperty("DocumentElement");


                               StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


         for(int j=0;j<resDocEl.getPropertyCount();j++)
         {
            SoapObject resTable= (SoapObject)resDocEl.getProperty(j);

            String MagazaObjId      =resTable.getProperty("MagazaObjId").toString();
            String MagazaAdi        = resTable.getProperty("MagazaAdi").toString();
            String MagazaKodu       = resTable.getProperty("MagazaKodu").toString();
           String MagazaPosDepoNo  =resTable.getProperty("MagazaPosDepoNo").toString();
           String PosId            = resTable.getProperty("PosId").toString();
           String IsYeriObjId      = resTable.getProperty("IsYeriObjId").toString();                                   

           stringBuilder.append
           (                                             
              "MagazaObjId     :" +MagazaObjId+"\n"+
              "MagazaAdi       :"  +MagazaAdi+"\n"+
              "MagazaKodu      :" +MagazaKodu+"\n"+
              "MagazaPosDepoNo :"+MagazaPosDepoNo+"\n"+
              "PosId           :" +PosId+"\n"+
              "Type            :" +IsYeriObjId+"\n"+
              "******************************"
           );

           stringBuilder.append("\n");                                       
       }                                 
     tv.setText(stringBuilder);                                             
                       }
                       catch(Exception e)
                       {
                              tv.setText(e.getMessage());
                       }
                }
         });


}

public static SoapObject getWebServisDATA(String pUrl, String pMethodName,String pNameSpace, String pSoapAction,String pname) 
{
  SoapObject result = null;
  SoapObject request = new SoapObject(pNameSpace, pMethodName);
  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
              SoapEnvelope.VER11);
  envelope.dotNet = true;
  request.addProperty("firma",pname);
  envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

  AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(pUrl);

  try {
        httpTransport.call(pSoapAction, envelope);
        result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
  } 
  catch (Exception e)
  {

  }

  return result;
```

}